# Why is std::queue::empty() not thread-safe? Shouldn't const functions be thread-safe?

Tags: multithreading, stl, queue

Why is the `empty()` function in `std::queue` not thread-safe? (See [here](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html).) Shouldn't `const` functions always be thread-safe, since it's read-only?

Maybe there may be some `mutable` variable in the class that may get written by the several threads?

Comment: Read-only functions aren't inherently threadsafe. They are safe *if there is no writing going on by other threads*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Methods that don't modify the data of a class are only thread-safe if the object is *never* modified by *any* method. Otherwise a method on another thread could change the object (under a lock, correctly) and calling `queue::empty()` on your thread without acquiring the lock could lead to a race condition (depending on its implementation).